# Unable to format my sandisk 64gb sd card

Tags: sd-card, format

I've been using my 64gb sd card (it came with an adapter) in my xperia z1 for a year. Later I used a few times for my DSLR Nikon D3300 with it's adapter. After using for about ten times in the camera, I was unable to delete the pics using my pc. I tried windows format, wasn't successful. Tried SD formatter. It always says the card is write protected, even if isn't. Ran chkdsk on it; got different results at different attempts. Looks like the dirty bit is set on it. What should I do now? Is this card toast?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to format 32GB micro-SD card](http://superuser.com/questions/196888/unable-to-format-32gb-micro-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try formatting the card from within the camera or the phone yet? Here are some how-tos:

Formatting the SD card in a Nikon:

http://www.wikihow.com/Format-a-Memory-Card-with-a-Nikon-D700

Formatting the SD card in an Xperia:

https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-11874#sd_card